# Xpath preceding-sibling (using HtmlAgilityPack and VB)

Tags: vb.net, xpath, html-agility-pack

Im using HtmlAgilityPack/HAP so that I can use Xpath with HTML documents.

I need help selecting the preceding-sibling of **div class="address"** in this url:
*[www.yellowpages.ca/search/si-geo/1/sh/Ottawa,+ON](http://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si-geo/1/sh/Ottawa,+ON)*
The sibling that I want is **h3 class="listingTitleLine"**

Here is a screenshot:

http://i55.tinypic.com/25gc4qo.png
Can I get some help please.

-Dd,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select the `preceding-sibling` H3 element with the class attribute value of "listingTitleLine":

```
preceding-sibling::h3[@class='listingTitleLine']
```

To select each of the H3 elements with a class attribute value of "linstingTitleLine" that are preceding-siblings of div elements with a class attribute value of "address":

```
//div[@class='address']/preceding-sibling::h3[@class='listingTitleLine']
```

Comment: your XPath expressions will select *all* preceding sibling h3 elements. If there's always only one, we're fine. Otherwise, @Datadyne should use `preceding-sibling::h3[@class='listingTitleLine']
[1]` to get the closest preceding sibling h3 element.

Comment: @LarsH if I wanted to get a count of a varied number of <h3> nodes (which have no attributes) only up to the <h2> that precedes them (and before the next <h2> that follows them) what would I change here: `//h2[3]/following-sibling::h2[4]/preceding-sibling::h3` ? There might be 3 <h3>'s as next siblings to an <h2> and the next <h2> might have 5, I need to get the exact number between the <h2>'s. At the moment all the <h3>'s to the root are counted when using the example snippet. TIA - Jeremy

Comment: @JerryOfPerth, that's a good question. There are answers to that type of question (selecting nodes between two specified notes) on SO, but it may not be easy to find them by searching. If you can't find them, I'd recommend posting a new question.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply @LarsH I've been working on this for 2 days, have scoured and tested quite literally 50+ SO posts as well as dozens externally and to be honest just came across your comment above: _your XPath expressions will select all preceding sibling h3 elements_ which is the closest I have found to at least explain/confirm what I've narrowed my issue down to, I thought maybe there was something minor to look back only to the target node (h2[3]) which is why I took a stab here. I will post as question. Thanks again.

Comment: @JerryOfPerth: OK. Please give my username a notification so I'll see your question, and be sure to mention whether XPath 2.0 is an option for you, because that will make a big difference.

Comment: I will most certainly do that. Late here in AU will do this in am. Thanks again.